# First time trying to run python from Powershell. Am I using the right command/ what do I need to do to permit use of Python?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command-line

I'm trying to run some Python files from command line, using PowerShell, but I'm really unfamiliar with the shell, and I've run into some issues trying to run python. I think there is some preparation process for python that I've missed, but I don't know what.

In trying to run Python through Powershell, I've tried installing Python 2.7 on my computer. While it changed the nature of the error message I was first receiving, it has otherwise not done much.

I've also tried doing some research to see what might be going wrong, personally, but I'm having some trouble finding an exact answer to my problem, and therefore figured I'd try asking, on here.

From what I've seen, online, I think this is the correct way to call and run a python file in Powershell. It's what I'm currently using:

```
PS C:\Users\nickd\documents\Coding\Comp_Sci_Class\Python\debugger> python my_test.py
```

This should run a program that tests whether or not a debugger is working. Instead, I get the following error message when I try and use the command 'python':

```
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python my_test.py
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

As such, I'm led to believe that there is some step in preparing Python for use on Windows Powershell that I'm just missing, but I'm not finding a clean cut answer for what that might be.

Could somebody please help me out, and describe what it is I might need to do? I know that what I'm missing is likely extremely simple, and I apologize upfront if this is a silly problem to have. That said, if somebody could point me in the right direction as to what I need to do, I'd be really grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: The shell searches for the `python` command in the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. It tries to find the program to run by appending the extensions listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable, e.g. "python.COM", "python.EXE", and so on.

Comment: Have you put Python in your PATH environment variables?  If not - I think Windows will only look in the folder you're in for a python executable before throwing the error you're getting.

Comment: If the .py file association is configured to run scripts, you should also be able to run `.\my_test.py`, or just `.\my_test` if ".PY" is in `PATHEXT`. There's an option in the installer to configure this, but I don't recall if it's enabled by default in the 2.7 installer.

Comment: @ColinMac, PowerShell doesn't implcitly check the current directory. We either need an explicit reference to "." (e.g. `.\python.exe`) or to add "." to `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't find where you have installed python. If you add the folder where python.exe is located to path then it will work.
See here https://superuser.com/a/143121

Answer (score 0):

You have to add location of `Python.exe` to your environment variable..

Your path might be `C:\Program Files\Python27`

Please follow the below steps :

```
1) Right Click on This PC (My Computer) and Select Properties ( Win Key + Pause key)
2) Click on Advance system setting from left pane
3) Click on Environment Variables...
4) select variable called "Path" from second list box
5) Click on Edit button below the same list box
6) Add python.exe full path ( do not include filename )
7) close all dialogs by clicking OK
8) restart your powershell | ISE
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.3, the PythonLauncher is installed with Python on Windows.  It is py.exe and is already in the PATH (c:\windows) if you did an "all users" installation.  The default installation of Python also registers py.exe as the default handler for .py files.

Normally, with py.exe registered as the default handler, `mytest.py` would be sufficient to run the script, but since Powershell doesn't search the current directory by default, you can use `.\my_test.py` if it is in the current directory.

Otherwise, just run `py my_test.py` (if "all users" installation) or add the user directory where `py.exe` was installed to `PATH` if not.  If you have multiple versions of Python installed, `py -3.6` (for example) will run Python 3.6.

More information:

- [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)
- [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#using-python-on-windows)